# grep in R with multiple numerical or defined variables

Tags: r, regex

Example Data

```
A<-c(1,4,5,6)
B<-c(4,6,7,8)
C<-c(6,9,1,2)
D<-c(5,6,7,3)
E<-c(10,11,12,19)
DF<-data.frame(A,B,C,D,E)

colnames(DF)<-c("A_1","B_1","C_2","D_2","TEST")


One<-1
Two<-2
```

I want to use grep to drop (make NA) my data based on conditions found in the last column.

```
DF[DF$TEST>15,grep(Two,colnames(DF))]<-NA
```

Works just fine

```
DF[DF$TEST>15,grep(Two|One,colnames(DF))]<-NA
```

Does Not

And just in case numerical data is slightly different

```
DF[DF$TEST>15,grep(2,colnames(DF))]<-NA
```

This works fine

```
DF[DF$TEST>15,grep(2|1,colnames(DF))]<-NA
```

This does not

Ideally I would like to be able to use grep to drop data based on several per-defined variables:

```
grep(One|Two|Three|Four)
```

or if dealing with numbers

```
 grep(1:4)
```

And I'm not sure if I can get away with addition in my regular expressions, but ultimately it would be easiest if I could do this:

```
DF[DF$TEST>15,grep(One+1,colnames(DF))]<-NA   #If I were trying to grep on 2
```

or

```
DF[DF$TEST>15,grep(One+1:One,colnames(DF))]<-NA   #If I were trying to grep on 1:2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a regex pattern from the variable names.

Something like

```
or <- function(...) paste0('(', paste(..., sep = '|'), ')')
or(One,Two)
## [1]  '(1|2)'
grep(or(One,Two), colnames(DF))
```

Comment: this exact problem has plagued me a week now for some reason, and this was the solution that worked. thanks from 10 years in the future!

Answer (score 2):

Try using `sapply` wrapped in `c`

```
  c(sapply(One:Two, grep, colnames(DF))
```

and perhaps wrapped in `unique` if needed.

--

I found that the argument order in the `grep` functions (as opposed to `stringr` functions) make for very neat *apply calls.